# FB Comments not logged in - Chrome/Safari

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, safari, comments, facebook-login

I am trying to switch from Disqus to Facebook comments, but I have issues with the comment widget.

Here's a sample page https://gongonbeater.com/articles/49/post+coronavirus++the+basket+unfinished

The issue is that even though I am logged in to Facebook, the comment box on the page doesn't show me as logged in. I have "Log In to Post" there button but in fact, when I click on it, I get an empty popup. This happens in Chrome/Safari (I can't even type in Safari) but when I tried it on Firefox, it worked perfectly.

Is there any settings to fix this?

Comment: This is probably an issue with 3rd-party cookies getting blocked. Other than telling users to relax their security settings, so that 3rd-party cookies will be accepted in the context of your site, there is not much you can do then.

Comment: @CBroe thanx! If I can even do that, it would be great! I've even tried it on my Android phone using the default Chrome and it still doesn't work. This is very bad since almost all Android devices using Chrome by default.